# Check if ascx control exist in precompiled asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, web, precompiled

I would like to check if an ASCX file exists before I open it because it is loadded dynamically. That should be easy by using the following code:`System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(controlPath))`. But this doesn't work in precompiled website because ASCX files don't exist anymore.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Update:**
I precompile a website without "Allow precompiled site to be updatable" option.

Comment: Do you know the class name of the control?

Comment: I bet you haven't even tried because everything you said is false. After you precompile a site usercontrols still exist exactly in the same location they were before precompiling the app. And BTW, there are more efficient ways to load a control

Comment: @kaveman, generally I don't know the class name of the control. I just know file's path.

Comment: @Leo, please pay attention to an update. With non-updatable precompiled website only pages (.aspx files, with content stripped) left in their original locations. ASCX and .master files are removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File.Exists will not work because when an .ascx is precompiled it will not be physically present on the disk.

HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.FileExists will not work as well, the default implementation is MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider, which expects files to be physically present on the disk.

In such scenario, TemplateControl.LoadControl use the BuildManager which already cached those virtual files, so their physical presence is not checked.

Using reflection, it's possible to check if these files are cached (read: exist):

```
public static bool IsPrecompiledFileExists(string virtualPath)
{
    Type virtualPathType = BuildManager.GetType("System.Web.VirtualPath", true);
    MethodInfo createMethodInfo = virtualPathType.GetMethod("Create", new Type[] {typeof(string)});
    object virtualPathObject = createMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { virtualPath });

    MethodInfo getVPathBuildResultFromCacheMethodInfo = typeof(BuildManager).GetMethod("GetVPathBuildResultFromCache", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    object buildResult = getVPathBuildResultFromCacheMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { virtualPathObject });
    return buildResult != null;
}
```

To make the solution compatible with additional deployment scenarios, you may probably want to use:

```
public static bool IsVirtualFileExists(string virtualPath)
{
    return HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.FileExists(virtualPath) ||
           IsPrecompiledFileExists(virtualPath);
}
```

**Edit:** [Peter Blum](https://weblogs.asp.net/peterblum/user-controls-and-the-publish-web-site-command) has a better and faster solution.

p.s. For .Net Framework 2.0, BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath could be used as well (We can learn if the file exist or not based on the exception thrown).

Comment: The Peter Blum link is nice.  For posterity, the relevant part is `if (System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(pVirtualFilePath, false) != null)`

Answer (score -2):

Some times you need to check if a user control exists before dynamically load it to a page. Here are two ways to accomplish this:

```
using System.Web.Hosting;
...

string virtualPath = "MyControl.ascx";
// or: "controls/MyControl.ascx"
// or: "../controls/MyControl.ascx"
// or: "~/controls/MyControl.ascx"

if (HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.FileExists(virtualPath))
{
Control control = LoadControl(virtualPath);
...
}
```

---

```
using System.IO;
...

string virtualPath = "MyControl.ascx";
// or: "controls/MyControl.ascx"
// or: "../controls/MyControl.ascx"
// or: "~/controls/MyControl.ascx"

if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(virtualPath)))
{
Control control = LoadControl(virtualPath);
 ...
}
```

Comment: It is check physically of any file on the disk.

Answer (score -3):

System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)) should do the trick. As @Leo said in your comment. 
ascx is a custom user control that is used in aspx page and they are still on the same location when you deployed your project.

Comment: This should do the trick only when a site precompiled with "Allow precompiled site to be updatable" option. In this case usercontrols still exist in the same location.

Answer (score -3):

```
 string ucName = "MyUC.ascx";
 if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/NameProject/" + (ucName))))
      controlToLoad = ucName;
LoadControl(controlToLoad);
```

Worked for me =))

Comment: I downvoted this because it does not work when the web-application is precompiled without updatable files, as the `*.ascx` file will **not** be physically present in the file-system, so this code will always return false.

Comment: I think you need try before comment =))

Comment: It won't work: `File.Exists` will return `false` and `controlToLoad` will be undefined (presumably `null`) and `LoadControl` will throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: You need to pass the path parameter to it. If not path will false..